# Indexing numpy array with an array of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 `numpy` arrays: `X` with shape `(..., 12, 3)` and `Y` with shape `(..., 12)`, where the `...` is the same in both cases. I get an array of indices using:

```
idx = np.argmin(Y, axis=-1)
```

which afterwards I want to use to get the corresponding elements from array `X` and `Y`. However, I run into issues due to the extra dimensions. For `Y`, I can do e.g.

```
Y[np.arange(Y.shape[0]), idx]
```

however this requires me to know the shape of `...` which will not be the case at all times. How do I do this in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since I figured it out, here is the way to do it:

```
idx = np.argmin(Y, axis=-1)
indices = np.indices(idx.shape)
min_from_X = X[indices[0], ..., idx, :]
min_from_Y = Y[indices[0], ..., idx]
```